# i want to make a shortcut for ugs with a icon ,completely new to ubuntu

Tags: launcher

i tried to run a script but the laucher shows there was an error launching the application

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=UGS Platform
Comment=UGS Platform is the next generation of Universal Gcode Sender.
GenericName=UGS Platform
Exec=~/Desktop/2Dplotter/ugs/ugs-platform-app-linux/ugsplatform-linux/bin$ ./ugsplatform
Type=Application
Icon=""
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
```

Comment: After `Exec=`, there should be a valid command. Check whether you can run the part after `Exec=` in a terminal. If not, then correct your command first.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the terminal, `~` is expanded by the shell to become the full path of your home directory, i.e. `/home/<yourlogin>`. In `.desktop` launchers, such expansion does not work. Resolution: replace `~` on the line `Exec=` by the full path of your home directory, e.g., assuming the username is `bens`, `/home/bens/Desktop/`.
2. Provide a valid command. You probably change first to the directory `/home/bens/Desktop/2Dplotter/ugs/ugs-platform-app-linux/ugsplatform-linux/bin` then execute the program as `./ugsplatform`. Try instead entering the correct path to that executable `./ugsplatform`

The final `Exec=` line then becomes:

```
Exec=/home/bens/Desktop/2Dplotter/ugs/ugs-platform-app-linux/ugsplatform-linux/bin/ugsplatform
```